# How can I Display Appointment Info in a Message Box?

Tags: vba, outlook, appointment

I want to pull the Appointment organizer, creation time and last modification time to display them in a message box.

```vb
Sub AppointmentDetails()

    Dim AppointmentItem As Object
    Set AppointmentItem = Application.ActiveInspector.CurrentItem

    Dim organizer As Object
    Set organizer = AppointmentItem.organizer

    Dim creationTime As Object
    Set creationTime = AppointmentItem.GetCreationTime

    Dim lastModification As Object
    Set lastModification = AppointmentItem.GetLastModificationTime

    MsgBox (organizer & vbNewLine & creationTime & vbNewLine & lastModification)

End Sub
```

Tweaking the script results in the debugger showing either error 424 or 461.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `"set"` only with objects, not with scalar values. The property names were also wrong (use `CreationTime` and `LastModificationTime`)

```
Sub AppointmentDetails()

    Dim AppointmentItem As Object
    Set AppointmentItem = Application.ActiveInspector.CurrentItem

    Dim organizer As Object
    organizer = AppointmentItem.organizer

    Dim creationTime As Object
    creationTime = AppointmentItem.CreationTime

    Dim lastModification As Object
    lastModification = AppointmentItem.LastModificationTime

    MsgBox (organizer & vbNewLine & creationTime & vbNewLine & lastModification)

End Sub
```